# I want to know what is the error in this SQL query

Tags: sql

I have updated the Query to

```
SELECT regexp_substr(a.NAME, '[^:]+$') AS emp_req
    ,a.COMPLETION_STATUS
    ,b.USER_TYPE
    ,b.display_name
FROM spt_result a
    ,spt_identity b
WHERE a.name LIKE 'Join%'
AND emp_req = b.display_name;
```

I want to fetch the user type from spt_identity table which is having completion status as error or success in `spt_result table` . the table `spt_result` contains

```
NAME                                           COMPLETION_STATUS 
----------------------------------------------------------------
Add/Remove Role(s) for:kc051363(1503085327459) Error 
Joiner:sk080281                                Success
```

and `spt_identity contains`

```
USER_TYPE         DISPLAY_NAME
-----------------------------
Parttime-Regular   pt092101 
Parttime-Regular   rm088923
Vendor             wl090918
Parttime-Regular   ne091924
Vendor             dh090040
```

Comment: How can we know what the error is in your SQL query if you don't tell us?

Comment: You have display_name as alias and actual column name. It may get confused.

Comment: Well I have changed it to :-select a.USER_TYPE,a.display_name,regexp_substr(b.NAME, '[^:]+$') as emp_name from spt_identity a,spt_task_result b where b.Name like 'Join%' and a.DISPLAY_NAME=b.emp_name;  still the error showing as ORA-00904: "B"."EMP_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 162

Comment: When asking SQL related question, you should post SQLs you used to create the tables, and if the question concerns query result, SQLs to insert data. Without these information, you may have made a mistake when creating the table and we will never know. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: b.emp_name does not exist. Its an alias for `regexp_substr(b.NAME, '[^:]+$')`, unless spt_task_result actually does have a column emp_name. Also, get rid of your old join syntax. That "from table1,table2" syntax died a slow but necessary death many years ago.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged+

Answer (score 0):

Join on occurrence of `DISPLAY_NAME` in `NAME`

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM spt_identity i
JOIN spt_result r ON INSTR(r.name, i.display_name) > 0
WHERE r.completion_status IN ('Error', 'Success')
```